# Turn retired-rope question into community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I like [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3952/what-can-i-do-with-a-retired-rope-and-harness) about retired climbing rope, but obviously there can be no correct answer. I therefore suggest we turn it into a community wiki. What do other people think?

Comment: I tend to agree

Answer (score 3):

"Community Wiki" was not really designed for this.

The problem with *most* list-style questions is that it becomes really hard to begrudge anyone their addition, and every suggestion of a random favorite tool/application/tip/trick/etc is no better than any other — so any semblance of "expert answers"  is lost.

But I don't really see a problem with this question. No, it's not the ideal "best answer rises to the top" query, but it seems well under control for the time being.

Community Wiki was *not* designed to solicit crowd-sourced lists of stuff, but the ***bigger* problem** with Community Wiki is it's often used to allow questions that otherwise would *not* be allowed on the site. That's why we largely deprecated the feature — [Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

My suggestion is… moderate the site for content however you see fit — fix the question, if it needs it. But please, **let's not (mis)use the Community Wiki feature** to somehow "fix" questions that you otherwise would not allow.